# Using PathLocationStrategy in Angular2-bundled Java application

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, angular2-routing

In one of our applications we are building an Angular 2 project and bundling it into the `webapp` folder of a JEE Web Application that is running on JBoss EAP. We would like to use the `PathLocationStrategy` for routing. However, when doing so, when the application page is refreshed on the browser, a 404 is being thrown. I am unable to understand where the problem is. Is it a common issue? Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: just forward your route to index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use PathLocationStrategy instead of HashLocationStrategy, then 404 error is obvious when refreshing your application as the actual address within the browser is updating. I had the similar problem and I was using nginx to serve angular2 app. I tried to solve it by replacing command inside location in project.conf (configuration for hosting application) file.

```
server {
    server_name my-app;

    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        //instead of 404 
    }
}
```

In case of nginx, this works! I don't have much knowledge about JBoss EAP though. You can follow [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) site as well. You might find what you are looking for here.